# how to Find and replace text in XML and avoid some text

Tags: javascript, automation, macros

I want to replace text in an XML file with a variable having tags. But I would not want to modify the text that is already within an element (`<keyword>`).

```
Find text = ABC
Replace = <keyword keyref="sname"><?xm-replace_text ABC?></keyword>
```

If the XML topic already has "`<keyword keyref="sname"><?xm-replace_text ABC?></keyword>`" i would not want the script to modify the "ABC" within the `<Keyword>` tag.